# what jar's should Web Component WEB-INF LIB should contain in a war file

Tags: java, web-inf

is web-inf/lib should contain only application specific jar's or deployment environment specific jar's also as per J2EE standards.

Note : war file is not making use of any deployment environment specific functionality (for instance weblogic or websphere or tomat etc ...)

Comment: Laxmikanth, Do you have a specific example of a conflicting jar which you want advise on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application specific jars and if you have multiple applications deployed on the same server/JVM then any jars whose classes (class instances) you don't want to share. For more details about my second point: [my earlier question about classloaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416517/classloader-behaviour-on-tomcat-with-multiple-applications)

Answer (score 1):

The WEB-INF/lib folder should contain your application specific jar files. Jar files that are global to the server will be stored in the server's classpath.